# Statistical uncertainty on count data from experiment

Tags: standard-error, uncertainty

I have run an experiment in which I'm comparing the behavior of two groups of unequal size (`group1` and `group2`), where each subject in the group **has** to take one two possible actions. So I'm ending up with data of the form:

```
        action_A    action_B
group1     3320       2273
group2    16154       9359
```

The results are currently being presented as a simple histogram, where we just plot the number of users that took each action separately for each group (and I do see a difference in the distribution between groups).

Without presenting some uncertainty on these numbers though, I have no confidence that the results are actually due to a real difference in the experiment, or just some statistical uncertainty.

I know this is a super naive question but if I understand it correctly then to use the square root of the number of entries in each group as the statistical uncertainty then this would have to be a Poisson process, which implies that one of the events is rarer than the other. As you can see from the above, this isn't really the case and the split is around 60/40 or so between the two actions.

What I'd love to be able to do is say that X% of group Y took action A (or B), and be able to quote a +/- value for the uncertainty (or just with raw numbers rather than as a percentage).

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) problem.  If so, you can confirm that Group 2 is 18% more likely (95% confidence interval: between 11% and 25% more likely) to do action A than B.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can set something up like: ``model <- glm(action ~ group, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = df)`` and the output gives coefficients of the form used in the "Probability of passing an exam versus hours of study" in the wiki page for LR. However, the group membership is encoded as a boolean, so I basically end up with an equation of the form: ``prob_action_A = 1/(1+exp(-(0.54583+-0.16697 *df$group)))`` which will evaluate to ~0.63 or 0.59 depending on whether the group is encoded as 1 or 0. Would you mind expanding on how I can get to this 18% with CL that you mentioned?

Comment: Assuming you've got a data.frame with columns, `a`, `b`, and `group` then `mod <- glm(cbind(a, b) ~ group, family=binomial, data=df)` gets you coefficients interpretable in terms of logits of the probability of action `a`, and exponentiating them gets you odds, as per the wiki page. So `exp(coef(mod))` gets you 1.18 = 18% increase, and `exp(confint(mod))` gets you upper and lower bounds.

Comment: I was going to say that, for this problem, choosing logistic regression over a chi-square test or a test of independent groups' proportions would be like getting out the snowblower when all you need to do is shovel 10 feet of walkway.  But @anthr you seem to be handling the snowblower just fine :-)

Comment: @rolando2 Well, he does want intervals around things, and I'm always keen to give people more rather than less general tools. Strategically speaking, I also bet there are covariates lurking in the back of this problem. There almost always are :-)

Comment: FYI, CIs in probability space: `g <- data.frame(predict(mod, se.fit=TRUE))` to get them in logit space, then `g$prob <- 1/(1+exp(-g$fit))` to get probabilities, `g$lwr <- 1/(1+exp(-(g$fit - 1.96*g$se.fit)))` to get lower, and `g$upr <- 1/(1+exp(-(g$fit + 1.96*g$se.fit)))` to get upper limits on them. R doesn't really make this easy...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of this @conjugateprior. I don't know if you're interested in pasting your responses as an answer but from your comments I feel as though the question has been answered. I will also compare the results to those from a chi-squared test, so rolando2, thanks for that suggestion :)

Comment: Yes, those comments did get a bit out of hand.  I'll paste some things in for the record.

Comment: Having checked my internal state, I can't be bothered. Happily there are plenty of good logistic regression explanations around here and elsewhere on the web. The key to your question, I think, is to set it up as such a model, and the rest is mechanical.

Comment: Just an FYI on covariates though.  If you do know something more about these folk than their group you might be able some interesting *conditional* treatment effects by interacting that information with the group indicator.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have spent on this. I have used LR many times for classification tasks but was nowhere near thinking of using it as an approach to this problem - clearly time to go revisit some notes. I'll think about this potential extension to conditional treatment effects too - this entire population is actually a sub-group of a larger population, so there might be more to do here :)